# Creating a function to calculate Partial Credit Model probabilities in R

Tags: r, function, probability

I am using the R package eRm and am trying to create a function which will calculate the probabilities given from the partial credit model.

The values I am working with are given below.

```
      [1]    [2]     [3]   
 Q1   -0.5   -0.2    0.7
 Q2   -1     -0.5    1.5 
 Q3   -2      0.1    1.9
```

The idea is that for Q1 I want the function to output 3 probabilities i.e.

```
exp(-0.5)/exp(-0.5)+exp(-0.5-0.2)+exp(-0.5-0.2+0.7)
exp(-0.5-0.2)/exp(-0.5)+exp(-0.5-0.2)+exp(-0.5-0.2+0.7)
exp(-0.5-0.2+0.7)/exp(-0.5)+exp(-0.5-0.2)+exp(-0.5-0.2+0.7)
```

I am having problems doing this, specifically, writing code so that for each successive iteration, the exponential sum in the numerator increases by one element. I have tried using `for()` in order to create a loop but I have not been able to get this to work.

As I am new to R I am unsure of what to try next or how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to apply the function to each row.

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  denom <- exp(x[1])+exp(x[1]+x[2])+exp(x[1]+x[2]+x[3])
  c(exp(x[1]) / denom,
    exp(x[1]+x[2]) / denom,
    exp(x[1]+x[2]+x[3]) / denom)
}

apply(dat, 1, myfun)

           Q1        Q2        Q3
[1,] 0.2883962 0.2312239 0.1053272
[2,] 0.2361188 0.1402444 0.1164045
[3,] 0.4754850 0.6285317 0.7782683
```

where `dat` is the name of your matrix.

If you want to obtain a matrix with the same orientation like your original matrix, you can use `t`:

```
t(apply(dat, 1, myfun))

        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
Q1 0.2883962 0.2361188 0.4754850
Q2 0.2312239 0.1402444 0.6285317
Q3 0.1053272 0.1164045 0.7782683
```

Comment: I see the idea behind this however what I expected out was probabilities. So Q1 has probabilities which sum to 1, as does Q2, Q3 etc...I do not understand why probabilities are not returned as your function looks as though it should work well

Comment: @zcakh07 What is the expected output for your example matrix?

Comment: Calculated by hand, for row Q1 the corresponding values are `0.288, 0.236, 0.475` respectively. These have been calculated using the formulae I have above.

Comment: @zcakh07 See the update. Your formula is lacking parentheses. Division is evaluated before addition.